# Is there a Method of verifying if a string contains only numbers in Java?

Tags: java, string

How do I check if a String contains only numbers (0 -9) without using regular expression in Java?

I should be able to do:

```
String str = "asdf123";
str.isDigit() //which should return false

String str = "123";
str.isDigit() //which should return true
```

Comment: Can you use Integer.parseInt();?

Comment: `boolean isDigit = theString.chars().allMatch(c -> '0' <= c && c <= '9')`. Though note that doesn't guarantee the number will _fit_ in an `int`; if that's important to you then I recommend Zahid's approach.

Comment: Does it have to be a parseable integer, or for example should `"999999999999999999999"` return true?

Comment: yes it should return true and "999999999999a" should return false

Comment: Note that you will not be able to do `someString.isDigit()` because `String` does not have an `isDigit()` method, nor can you add one to the class. All solutions are going to use `parseInt`, loops, streams, or regex either inline or extracted out into a method that accepts the input string.

Comment: @Slaw Well, not quite right. There are Extension Methods (Aspect Orienteded Design) that can be introduced into Java, for example via Project Lombok or AspectJ or many more Libraries/Frameworks. With those you can write such extension methods yourself in other classes, and literally write `str.isDigit()`. I do use them quite often, it's especially useful for null safety, or comfort (writing `a.or(b)` if a could be null, then use b, and many such cases). https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod

Comment: @JayC667 Yes, I was ignoring instrumentation, source code preprocessing, compiler hacks, and other approaches not built into the language itself.

Comment: Please note that `parseInt()` will also allow `+` and `-` - not sure if that is wanted or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no built-in method available in Java to check if the given string has only digits or not? but you can shorten the logic using without regular expression.

In below code, the **isDigit** method checks if all characters in the string are digits using the **str.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)** expression. It returns true if all characters are digits and false if any character is not a digit. This method is concise and checks the entire string in a single line of code.

```
public static boolean isDigit(String str) {
    return str.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
}
```

Comment: Same cautionary note I left on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77342516/is-there-a-method-of-verifying-if-a-string-contains-only-digit-in-java#comment136349264_77342549). It's possible `Character#isDigit(char)` would work for the OP, but not according to the question as currently asked.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own function:

```java
boolean isDigitsOnly(String str){
  int number = 0;
  try {
    if(str == null){
      return false;
    }
    Integer.parseInt(str);
    return true;
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: a regular expression will take at most 2 lines of code. yours have taken more

Comment: @oseghalealoysius Please reread the question, the ask is not to use regex.

Comment: @oseghalealoysius You asked for a solution other than regex, not one that's shorter than regex.

Comment: Please note that this solution will also accept numbers starting with `+` or `-` not just digits "*(0-9)*" - maybe required or may not...

Answer (score -1):

> *"... How do I check if a String contains only numbers (0 -9) without using regular expression in Java? ..."*

Use a *loop*, and the *[Character#isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))* method.

```java
boolean isDigit(String s) {
    int i = 0, n = s.length();
    do if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) return false;
    while (++i > n);
    return true;
}
```

Or, use a *String*.

```java
boolean isDigit(String s) {
    String d = "0123456789";
    int i = 0, n = s.length();
    do if (!d.contains(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)))) return false;
    while (++i > n);
    return true;
}
```

Or, a *stream*.

```java
boolean isDigit(String s) {
    return s.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
}
```

Output

```
isDigit("asdf123") = false
isDigit("123") = true
```